# How do prove that the Lie derivative of a k-form commutes with its action on k vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, lie-derivative

In Proposition 13.11 of Lee's Smooth Manifolds book he asserts that for smooth $k$-form $\sigma$ and vector fields $X, Y_1,...,Y_k$ we have
$\mathcal{L}_X(\sigma(Y_1,...Y_k)) = (\mathcal{L}_X\sigma)(Y_1,...,Y_k) + \sigma(\mathcal{L}_XY_1,...,Y_k) + ... + \sigma(Y_1,...,\mathcal{L}_XY_k) $. He provides no proof, and I am not finding it anywhere near so straightforward as he asserts-- we can use $\mathcal{L}_X(\sigma(Y_1,...Y_k)) = X(\sigma(Y_1,...,Y_k)) $ but it is not at all clear how to proceed from here. Does anyone have a proof of this result?

(Note: $\mathcal{L}_X$ is the Lie Derivative, here defined as $\mathcal{L}_X(\sigma) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(\theta_t)^*\sigma_{\theta_t(p)} - \sigma_p}{t}$ where $\theta$ is the flow of $X$)

Comment: what does $\mathcal{L}_X$ mean?

Comment: It's the Lie Derivative, $\mathcal{L}_X(\sigma) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(\theta_t)^*\sigma_{\theta_t} - \sigma_p}{t}$ where $\theta$ is the flow of $X$

Comment: are you referring to proposition 12.32(d)?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about Lie derivatives in Proposition 13.11, in either the first or the second edition of my Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. You must be looking at one of the pirated draft versions of the first edition, which somebody posted illegally on the internet. Those are full of mistakes and come with no guarantees.

Comment: Well, this is awkward for me! Actually, I was under the impression that this book was freely accessible, given that when I google "Lee Smooth Manifolds" the first result is a pdf of the entire second edition (not, apparently, the pirated draft edition I apparently ended up with) available no less from Berkeley's website! (Look here if you don't believe me: https://math.berkeley.edu/~jchaidez/materials/reu/lee_smooth_manifolds.pdf)

Comment: @Art: I've seen that Berkeley site. It's also an illegal post, in blatant violation of the copyright, and it's far from the only example. But it's up to Springer to pursue copyright violations. My concern is that it's annoying and frustrating to have people reading a rough draft that was never intended for public distribution, and thinking they're reading my text.